# What is the safe way to store the downloaded images in android

Tags: android, image

I need to store the list of downloaded image in device.I need to know what is the best way for storing images.If i store it in sd card when the user removes the sd card from device.In that situation how to overcome this problem.

Comment: what is max size of all image files can user scarify the phone memory for your app

Comment: Is there the possibility of removing default sd card from android mobile

Comment: if there is a inbuild sd card then i don't think you can remove it

Comment: ok thnaks for your response.i'm having more images from internet to save in device.what is the best way to save the images in internal memory or external sd card

Comment: It depends upon the total size i don't think user will bear an application which takes too much space untill unless he/she is not forced to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bothering about the `sdCard removal` then only on option is available to save on phone memory that is always available.

Or if you have Internet available what about moving to cloud ???

but if the main concern is security of Images you can go with the  answer of user @[shree202](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1739882/shree202) 
For the security purpose you can change the extension

Say From `JPG ==>> .db`

it is use less for other applications and also user manually can't change the extension

and also for more secure way You can encrypt it by changing it to byte.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to open the images right from your own application, then, you can remove the extension of the image file and then save. After that, while accessing the image you can get the file list and display it again in your application by appending the file extension.